# Need to add text image and save it in file using lightning or any tool in salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, html, node.js, angularjs, js

i have lightning component which will browse and upload image into document object.

Requirment -- in lightning component i have one text box.
Text should get added over image and  then save image in document .

I am not geting any way to do this.
Please help.how can we achieve this
Any external library or js we can use?

Answer (score 1):

All the tools you need are already in your browser and the Lightning core library. You just need to use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader)  to read the image, [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) to render the image and text overlay, and [force:recordData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/documentation) (or just plain Apex) to save the file.

I even took a brief moment to write up a demo of a [text overlay system in Lightning Web Components](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/tu9sGgGRtgb6Fm16pEcQ), it's only about 40 lines of code, not at all complicated. In Aura, it would be slightly longer because of certain ways that Aura does things, but it's not difficult to find what you need in the documentation.

If you have specific problems and get stuck in your coding, please feel free to ask specific questions, and we'll be glad to help you out. However, we are not a code writing service, and are not here to literally write your code for you.

Please read [How to Ask](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better understanding of what we expect in questions in order to be able to adequately answer your questions within the narrow scope of our community's rules.

I've only provided this as an answer rather than a comment because it exceeded the length of even a few comments, and I did want to provide you with a starting point that would be useful, but please don't expect answers like this in the future. You will be expected to show your work and abide by our rules to get further assistance.